# Loading and Eigen Matrix from yaml using yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, eigen3, yaml-cpp

I'm using the very nice [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) project to read configurations into a C++ program.  One of the config items stores an Eigen::Matrix<..>  The following code works well but wondering if there is a better way?

main.cpp:

```
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("default.config");

const vector<double> eigenVec = config["my_matrix"].as<vector<double>>();

// https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html
Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4,Eigen::RowMajor> Matrix4x4(eigenVec.data());
cout << "Matrix  : " << Matrix4x4 << endl;
```

config.yaml:

```
my_matrix: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 7.0, 3.0, 0.0,
        3.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0 ]
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to save as binary like [`npy`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html) format? Decimal is not a wise choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can compressed into one line of the code

```
Eigen::Matrix4d Matrix4x4= Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, Eigen::RowMajor>>(config_node_["my_matrix"].as<std::vector<double>>().data());
```